# Get number from an url

Tags: php, regex

We have an url like http://site.com/people/593765-barack-obama?sort=popular

How do I get only the ID part of the link? It is 593765 for this example.

So the pattern is `http://site.com/people/{somenumber}-{anythingelse}`

I'm not sure how to get it by using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('#/(\d+)-#', $url, $m);
echo $m[1]; // 593765
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess shorts is a 'catch' file for the URL, and the {somenumber}-{anythinelse} is a parameter you obtain, I would just explode the parameter.

```
list($iNumber, $sAnything) = explode("-", $sParam1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern:

```
#/(\d+)-.+\??#
```

Usage example:

```
preg_match('#/(\d+)-.+\??#', 'http://site.com/people/593765-barack-obama?sort=popular', $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
string(6) "593765"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

`/people\/([0-9]+)\-/`

```
<?php
    //$pattern = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pattern = "http://site.com/people/593765-barack-obama?sort=popular";
    preg_match('/people\/([0-9]+)\-/', $pattern, $match);
    if (isset($match[1])) {
        echo "The number is: " . $match[1];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to filter it from

`/shots/593765-brainzap?list=following`

which is the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` of the page.